# Images aren't being displayed as embedded in email sent by my application

Tags: delphi, email, gmail, indy

I'm trying to send an email with embedded images through a delphi application using Indy, but somehow it isn't working.

I compared the contents of the email I sent with one sent from gmail, and everything seens fine, but I might be missing some little detail.

Gmail shows the attached image of my email as a normal attachment, but it is set correctly as inline.

**EDIT**

Solved using the [TIdMessageBuilderHtml](http://www.indyproject.org/Sockets/Blogs/RLebeau/20080116.EN.aspx) it worked perfectly on the first try.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved using the [TIdMessageBuilderHtml](http://www.indyproject.org/Sockets/Blogs/RLebeau/20080116.EN.aspx) it worked perfectly on the first try.

Just a few lines of code:

```
  with TIdMessageBuilderHtml.Create do
    try
      Subject := 'example';
      Html.Text := 'HTML goes here';
      HtmlFiles.Add('c:\folder\image1.jpg');
      HtmlFiles.Add('c:\folder\image2.jpg');
      FillMessage(IdMessage1);
    finally
      Free;
    end;
```